# Multiple dateRangeInput used in the for while loop

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny, lapply

I am new in R and shiny. Depending on the number of the date range input. I would like to get the start and end dates for each date range input and store it in a list.

for example:

Trend Date Range 1:
2010-01-01 - 2010-12-31

Trend Date Range 2: 
2011-01-01 - 2011-12-31

So when I run Trend.List it will show. This is the output that I want to achieve.

> Trend.List
>   [[1]]
>   2010-01 2010-12

[[2]]
2011-01 2011-12

I still want to calculate between those 2 dates.

I am not sure how to best code this in R and shiny since I am new to this.

Thanks for all your help!

See code

```
ui <-fluidPage(
               numericInput("numoftrends", 
               label="Number of Linear Trends:", 
               min=0, 
               max=10, 
               value=0,
               step=1),
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.numoftrends > 0",
                     uiOutput("num_of_trends")
                    ),
    actionButton("submit", "Submit")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

   output$num_of_trends <- renderUI({

   lapply(1:input$numoftrends, function(i) {

    tagList(dateRangeInput('DateRange(i)',
                           label = paste('Trend Date Range Input', i, ':'),
                           separator = " - ", 
                           format = "yyyy-mm",
                           startview = 'year'
             )

   })

})

 observeEvent(input$submit, {
   Trend.list <- list()
   for (a in 1:input$numoftrends) {
     start.date <- input$DateRange[a][1]
     end.date <- input$DateRange[a][2]

    diff <- end.date - start.date

    Trend.list[[a]] <- input$DateRange[a]
    }

    Trend.list

 })

 }

 shinyApp(ui= ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you provide error free code? When I run this code, I get errors when the app is up. I do not see the data file `SBI` too

Comment: I'm sorry but this code is not error free because it still a Work in Progress. Can I provide you a much simpler code that would work? If that helps. Thank you for looking into this. Please let me know if could send the code in this comment.

Comment: Anything that will help reproduce the issue and look into it. You can edit the question with new code

Comment: Hi krish - I have updated my code. the observeEvent is where I am having problems with in the start.date and end.date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making them have different labels, but their input object is the same (all named `'DateRange(i)'`). You need to change both to be able to refer to them.

An observer is also the incorrect method to use here, you should use a `reactive` as I've shown below. If you really need the submit button to stop processing of, use an `eventReactive` to generate the data.

In addition, making the conditional panel reliant on the number of trends probably not the best way -- I suggest using a checkbox.

```
library("shiny")

ui <-fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("add_trend", "Add Trend(s)"),
  conditionalPanel(condition="input.add_trend === true",
                   numericInput("numoftrends",
                                label="Number of Linear Trends:",
                                min = 1,
                                max = 10,
                                value = 1,
                                step = 1),
                   uiOutput("num_of_trends"),
                   textOutput("see_ranges")
  ),
  actionButton("submit", "Submit")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$num_of_trends <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:input$numoftrends, function(i) {
      dateRangeInput(paste0("date_range_input", i), paste('Trend Date Range Input', i, ':'),
                     separator = " - ",
                     format = "yyyy-mm",
                     startview = 'year')
    })
  })

  trend_list <- reactive({
    out <- list()
    for(i in 1:input$numoftrends) {
      out[[i]] <- input[[paste0("date_range_input", i)]]
    }
    out
  })

  output$see_ranges <- renderPrint({
    print(trend_list())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello mlegge. Thank you for your time in looking into this. I've been learning a lot from you for R and shiny.  This is what I am looking for. Now I have to learn reactive and Eventreactive. You have a great day! Cheers